# Search text file for word from list then output word that matched in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have been searching a large directory of text files for files that match a list of words. How do I have python output the word from the list that matches?

This is what I have so far. It writes the file name every time one of the words from the list is found. I want to add the matching word to the line with the file name so I have the file name and 1 matched word each time. How do I do that?

```
ngwrds= ['words'...]

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if any(x in line for x in ngwrds):
                    with open("keyword.txt", 'a') as out:
                        out.write(filename + '\n')
```

The input is a long text file a line might read like this:

The company reported depreciation of $1.20.

The if one of the search words from the list was depreciation then the output file would look like this:

filename depreciation

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of your input and desired output?

Comment: I added an example of the input and output

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `out` is and I can't run your code from where I am but you could try something like this:

```
ngwrds= ['words'...]

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            line = line.strip().split(" ")
            for word in line:
                if word in ngwrds:
                    out.write(filename + " " + word)
```

`strip` gets rid of whitespace on either end of `line`. `split` returns a list of the words in `line`.